# Drupal Views rendering duplicate rows in field based display

Tags: drupal, view, duplicates, cck, drupal-fivestar

I'm having issues with a sortable list view on my Drupal site. On random occasions, some rows duplicated. The only thing different between the 2 is their vote count from the Fivestar module. I'm assuming this may be the issue, but it could be a simple Drupal issue that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting in the view UI that will deal with duplicate values usually. It will make the query more complex and possibly slower so use it sparingly but it should solve your issue.

Comment: I've poked around but I can't find the setting your referring to. Do you know where I could find it?

Comment: I skitched where the setting is! https://skitch.com/smilner/rqtkd/edit-view-blog-categories-smithmilner.com